# wso2 esb - problems with XML to JSON conversion

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 and I have the following problems converting an xml (from an xslt output) to a json:

- strings with numbers automatically get converted as integer elements: "orderId": 10000 ( I want it to be string "orderId": "10000" )
- xml list come as json object if there is one element and as json array if more than one element is present..How can I tell the converter "this particular item must always be an array" ?

I'm using xslt to build the xml (as I have variuos xml to merge from some external system calls) and then use the property messageType application/json.

I can't use the payloadFactory since I have some logics to implement and use the script mediator with javascript instructions semms to me like a worst solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To get this done you can change the JSON Message Formatters.
Go to [ESB Home]/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml.

Change the JSON Message Formatters 
instead of JsonStreamFormatter use org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter

```
<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/-->
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter"/>
```

Note. here all values would be strings.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that several conversion options are on the desk to map between XML and JSON. I would recommend to use another xslt, to map previous to be sent between your xml and json, and then send the json. Maybe, even you can put all this logic into a sequence, and call that sequence from all the points you need.

For an example of xslt, see http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm not sure that wso2 support XSLTJSON. It does ignore functions like json:force-array="true". I'm only using a standard xslt to create an xml structure. Then I use this property `<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>` that will convert the xml as json. So I don't see any way to force int to string or object to array.

Comment: I don't mean that you use the xslt "as is", but it can help you to see how to implement your custom one. The option you are suggesting is "automatic" xml/json conversion. I don't know if there is any property that can do what you need, but you can surf the code to know if it is possible. That is the great thing of open source!

Comment: Thanks..I found that staxon (used from wso2 xml to json converter) support for example the tag <?xml-multiple?>. Using that tag before an xml element tell the converted to treat the element as an array. Now what I can't find is how to mark strings to not be converted in integer.