# WSO2 set a property type is string but change to integer

Tags: wso2

I set a property type is string as below:

```
<property name="result" scope="default" type="STRING" value="0"/>
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
        <jsonObject>
            <result>$1</result>                             
         </jsonObject>
      </format>
      <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:result"/>         
      </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

But the response result is integer.What happened?

```
{
        "result": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Property value is not a response content. How you make your response body? May be you use payloadFactory?

You can found something about json types in payload https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-json-magic-in-wso2-esb-5.0.0 and [wso2 esb - problems with XML to JSON conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870347/wso2-esb-problems-with-xml-to-json-conversion)

Comment: I already added my payload as above.I use your commend to add the synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive = false in "synapse.properties" file but what is "Copy the built jar into the directory repository/components/dropins"?Where can I find the built jar?By the way, I add force=”string” attribute to the elements but the response like this: { "result": { "@force": "STRING", "$": "0" } } This is not what I want. ....

Answer (score 0):

You've specified your payloadFactory to use xml. I am assuming later on, you convert that xml to json.

In xml, there is no  concept of "string" vs "integer" - unless you use xsd's - so when the ESB/EI converts the xml to json, it will convert the value to an integer if it sees a number, and a string if it doesn't.

XML -> JSON conversion is not type safe. Can you not use a json payloadFactory:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{  "result": "$1" }</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:result"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
```